# Sorting Number in a JTable issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable, numbers, tablerowsorter

How do I realize sorting of columns containing.
I set Cloumnclass is Number.Class

```
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
return Number.class;
}
```

and Create TableRowSorter

```
TableRowSorter sorter= new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table_mode);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

The result `8, 80, 9, 989` instead `989 , 80, 9, 8`

Comment: Read Oracle docs before asking http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of TableRowSorter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html):

> `TableRowSorter` uses `Comparator`s for doing comparisons. The following defines how a `Comparator` is chosen for a column:
>
> 1. If a `Comparator` has been specified for the column by the `setComparator` method, use it.
> 2. If the column class as returned by `getColumnClass` is `String`, use the `Comparator` returned by `Collator.getInstance()`.
> 3. **If the column class implements `Comparable`, use a Comparator that invokes the `compareTo` method.**
> 4. If a `TableStringConverter` has been specified, use it to convert the values to `String`s and then use the `Comparator` returned by `Collator.getInstance()`.
> 5. **Otherwise use the `Comparator` returned by `Collator.getInstance()` on the results from calling `toString` on the objects.**

The third and fifth rule are the cause of your issue:  You are returning [Number.class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), which does not implement Comparable.  Therefore, your table is sorting using the fifth rule:  your values are being treated as Strings.

Instead of returning Number.class, you need to return something which actually implements Comparable, such as Integer.class, Double.class, or BigDecimal.class.  The javadoc of each class will tell you what interfaces it implements.

Alternatively, you could install a custom Comparator on the table column, but your Comparator will have to do the work of casting the values and possibly converting them.  Returning a Comparable class is much easier.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't an issue with RowSorter and Number instance (all data types that is implemented in API(s) for JTable, its rendere, editor), if yes is there some..., then about guessing without OPs SSCCE/MCVE

Comment: agree with Double, Integer, Long instead of Number.class